# Labview FPGA VI call from two different program

Tags: parallel-processing, fpga, labview

I am new to LABview and FPGA programming. Now, i have compactRIO module with FPGA VI capturing 16 I/O ports details. Now, i want to read this FPGA VI from two different program. Is it possible to achieve it either simultaneously or in sequence?

Kindly advise. Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: How you are going to read FPGA VI from Host? :)

Comment: Maybe the problem should be rephased as " two programs or vi running on the host need to access data from the same FPGA". Correct?

Comment: Sorry for wrong statement. Now i have edited it. Let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: The best answer to this question will depend on how fast the data is being sampled, whether you need the host software to receive every sample taken or just see the latest value, and what you mean by 'two different programs' - are these two LabVIEW VIs, two LabVIEW built applications, or two programs written in some other language? You'll probably get better results asking on the NI forums, once you can answer those questions.

Comment: Also the CompactRIO developer guide is worth reading through - even if you're using different NI hardware the principles are the same: http://www.ni.com/compactriodevguide/